# Codeigniter Updating database table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I already can update my data from database but the problem is i just want to update one data, but when I enter the new data it updated all of data in the database table

like this
[image]

this is View:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>user/update_user_data">

<div class="form-group">
    <label> Enter New first name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Enter New last name </label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Enter New fullname </label>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" />


<div class="form-group">  
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
</div>
```

this is model:

```
function update_data($id = FALSE)  
  {  

    if($id == FALSE){
            $query = $this->db->get('user');
            return $query->result_array(); 
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('user', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row_array();
  } 
 public function update_user_data($data)
    { 
        $data = array('firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                        'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                        'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname')


                      );

        $this->db->update("user", $data);
    }
```

this is controller:

```
    public function update_data($id = NULL)
    {

        $data['us'] = $this->User_Model->update_data($id);

        if (empty($data['us'])) {
            show_404();
        }
         $this->load->view('user/update-user', $data);
    }

    public function update_user_data()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Update user';

            $this->load->library('upload');
                $data =  array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->User_Model->update_user_data($data);

            redirect('user/index');

    }
```

Im just a beginner please respect thanks
If there is something wrong with my code please let me know.
Its working by the way, the only problem is once I update the users data it updating all of the data in the database.

Comment: you're `updating` the whole table not `inserting`

Comment: You should add the ID of the row you want to update to the call

Comment: for update query need where condition,use id in where condition

Comment: and by the way @Eduards, yes im 'updating' not 'inserting'. My problem is instead of updating 1 row its updating all of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying every row in the table because of you have not given any specific row. And for this reason every row is updated after update code runs. you should use below code

```
function update_data($id = FALSE)  
  {  

    if($id == FALSE){
            $query = $this->db->get('user');
            return $query->result_array(); 
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('user', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row_array();
  } 
 public function update_user_data($data)
    { 
        $data = array('firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                        'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                        'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname')


                      );

        $this->db->where('id','1')->update("user", $data); //change id as require your own need
    }
```